# Is it possible to change pagination entries on Kaminari adding pages using bisection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

I need to obtain the following behavior using Kaminari.
If the page number is lower than 10 the standard behavior will be fine.
But when the page number grows, I need to reduce the number of clicks done by users using a bisection approach.

The following example explain the output.
[image: Example for page 25]

I’ve already read the Kaminari documentation but the provided customizations doesn't seem to provide a way to do it.

Has somebody already faced this issue?